# Web server seems to keep serving old images, issue with Apache & VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, virtualbox, cache

I'm asking this here because I'm pretty sure it's a Linux issue.

I'm running Apache server locally on Ubuntu Server 12.10, which runs inside a virtual machine (VirtualBox) on Windows 7. The "www" directory is shared between the Ubuntu VM and my Windows OS, using VirtualBox's "Share Folder" facitility.

**NOTE:** It's basically a local directory in windows. In Ubuntu it gets automatically mounted on startup.

The server is also accessible from my Windows host via a URL like `http://192.168.56.101/website1`.

The thing is that images from that URL appear to be cached until I restart the virtual machine.

For example:

The URL `http://192.168.56.101/website1/images/bg.png` on the Apache server running on Ubuntu points to this file `c:\www\website1\images\bg.png` on the Windows share. In the Ubuntu VM it exists under `/var/www/website1/images/bg.png`.

If I modify this file in Photoshop in my Windows host, the changes are not seen in the Ubuntu server. I suspect that Linux caches the file or something, because after restarting the VM I'll seeing the updated image.

Is there any way I could disable caching for anything under the `/var/www` directory? Would this decrease performance or something?

Comment: have you try Ctrl + F5 in your brother ?

Comment: well that's a rocky mistyping... browser is definitely the word I was looking for... anyway thanks for the answer it was pretty nice :D

Comment: It's not the browser because after I refresh it displays the old image. But if I restart the VM, then refresh again it displays the updated image

Comment: What if you empty the browsers cache?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with your browser cache. We'll need to look at the config to be able to tell you more.

Comment: It can't be the browser cache. Why doesn't it reload the image if I refresh then? And why is it updated only after I restart the virtual machine?

Comment: Linux does have a page cache; if it somehow doesn't realize that the files in the shared folder have changed, it may be at fault. Try to dump the page cache with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and see if that changed anything.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921670/prevent-virtualbox-guest-from-delivering-cached-files

Comment: This does sound exactly as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache

Comment: Yes I would agree, this is the best lead thus far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache/6511441#6511441

Comment: This is a 6 year old issue: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819. This entire issue is a little self imposed when one uses the VBoxFS to access folders from a guest to the host system. This is really not meant to be used for setting up accesses like this, but it is workable. Dropping the caches fixes the problem but has other side-effects and shouldn't be viewed as a solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem sounds exactly like the one that's described here: [Shared folder in VirtualBox for Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache/6511441#6511441)

Try to add this setting to your Apache configuration:

```
EnableSendfile off
```

Comment: Issue from VB's forums: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33201

Comment: ok I've added that line to apache2.conf, restarted apache and now it works fine. I also tried the command you posted in the comments above and that works too, so it has something to do with the linux cache :D